# Problema al insertar en base de datos con springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo un problema a la hora de insertar ficheros geojson en la base de datos.

He tenido que crear un método para crear instancias sin poder utilizar DAOS, se que está mal pero es la única manera de poder hacer lo que me han pedido.

Este es mi método:

```
private void insertIntoTable(String nameTable, JSONArray properties, ArrayList<Object> geometries) {
    for (int i=0; i<properties.length(); i++) {
        Object property = properties.get(i);
        Object geometry = geometries.get(i);
        String SQL = "INSERT INTO " + nameTable + " ( properties, geom ) VALUES ( '" + property + "', ST_Force3D(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('" + geometry + "'), 4326) ));";
        executeSQL(SQL);
    }
}
```

El problema es que cuando inserto una descripción con un caracter con comilla simple peta porque el string en el que defino el INSERT la comilla simple.

```
INSERT INTO chicago_parks_2 ( properties, geom ) VALUES ( '{"description":"A lakefront park on Chicago's south side","title":"Burnham Park"}', ST_Force3D(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"coordinates":[-87.603735,41.829985],"type":"Point"}'), 4326) ));
```

Si os fijais el apostrofe o comilla simple de Chicago's hace que pete.

He pensado en reemplazar la comilla simple por \' pero esto soluciona el problema con las comillas simples, pero seguro que más adelante pasa algo con otro caracter.

¿Se os ocurre otra solución?

Saludos

Comment: Escapa los caracteres problemáticos con la \

Comment: Si estás usando Spring Boot... ¿por qué no usar JPA y usar repositorios?

Comment: Lo sé.. pero es que me han pedido que lo haga así por una movida. Soy un mandao

Comment: Pero porque no te permiten utilizar  JPA?

Comment: porque lo que envio en un geojson y lo q serian las columnas del dao son las propiedades del geojson. y cada fichero puede tener n propiedades y no son siempre las mismas. Mi idea era usar mongo por delante para ese tipo de requests, pero no me dejaron